# When do I need to include armv7? Can I build for iOS5 devices too using only armv6?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, armv7

I am making a game that I want compatible for all older devices to as long as they all run on iOS4.0 or above. I do have some features specific for iOS5.

Now while making the build should i use both armv6 as well as armv7 architectures or can I just use armv alone? I am using xcode 4.2

Any explanation regarding this would be much appreciated. While I do know how to make it compatible for older devices I need some clarifications on when armv7 is required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to add armv6 support when limiting apps to iOS 4.0+?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517822/do-i-need-to-add-armv6-support-when-limiting-apps-to-ios-4-0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

armv7 is for iPad, iPad 2, iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, and iPhone 4s.

Comment: armv7 devices can run armv6 apps.  armv6 devices cannot run armv7 apps.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. Also, what is the advantage of using armv7? It seems to make my binary bigger and i would assume the overhead in computing would also be more than that of armv6. If the new devices are backward compatible with armv6 then how would I know if I require armv7 or not?

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies my question!