# Limit devices that app can run

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have found this great answer with this list

[Do I need to add armv6 support when limiting apps to iOS 4.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517822/do-i-need-to-add-armv6-support-when-limiting-apps-to-ios-4-0)

```
ARMv8 / ARM64 = iPhone 5s, iPad Air, Retina iPad Mini
ARMv7s = iPhone 5, iPhone 5c, iPad 4
ARMv7  = iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, iPod 3G/4G/5G, iPad, iPad 2, iPad 3, iPad Mini  
ARMv6  = iPhone, iPhone 3G, iPod 1G/2G
```

So if I want limit my app to be run on iPhone 5 and higher, can I just remove armv7 architecture from Xcode, or Apple reject this kind of limitation?

Just to be clear I don't want to limit with iOS version, I just want to support iPhone 5 and higher with latest iOS version. Is it possible?

Comment: The answer I want to know is Why?

Comment: @rckoenes Performance issues, designing app only for bigger screens,etc.. Cases can be different. I just never tried to eliminate devices with architecture, and how Apple reacts on it

Comment: performance issues can be solved, design for the 4" screen not! Especially with the two new screen size you will need to handle if you want to support the new devices.

Comment: Well I didn't say it can't . But my question is different,what if I just don't want to support lower than iPhone 5, (doesn't matter exactly WHY) , I wonder is it possible with such solution or no

Comment: Well yes I understand your question, but I'm just suggesting that you should try and support all devices which can run iOS 8. But Why not just try and upload a binary with ARMv7S and ARM64 only and see what happens

Comment: Yes regarding supporting all devices is tricky, like if is effort is much, and old devices market is very small, it not always best idea, but in general if it doesn't take much effort , of course it's better. Yes if nobody has ever experienced , I will do it, and reply to my question with what I have got.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/ios-iphone-get-device-model-and-make

Comment: its not possible to limit devices for app.. check this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498003/limit-app-to-running-only-on-4-inch-devices-ios]